# create dummy indicator for each variable in a data frame with specific values

Tags: r, dummy-variable

I have 115 variables in my data frame, and I need to create a dummy variable for each variable that has negative value or values of 999. The dummy indicator will take a value of 1 if the original x value is <0 or 999 and 0 otherwise. For example for the following data frame

```
at<-c(1,-9,-1,999)
Bc<-c(1,-2,999,0)
df<-data.frame(at,Bc)
```

I want to have an output dataframe with the following format:

```
at        Bc    I.at    I.Bc
 1         1      0       0
-9        -2      1       1
-1        999     1       1
999        0      1       0
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are many ways to add variables to a data frame. Base R: `df$Iat <- ifelse( df$at < 0 | df$at == 999, 1,0 )`

Comment: well, your code is what i knew but since i have 115 variables in my data set and i want to create this indicator for each one of them, thats where i got stuck and i was wondering if i could do this for all the variables at once and not separately for each one of them.

Comment: `dplyr::mutate_all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a base R solution like this:

```
transform(df,I=ifelse(df<0|df==999,1,0))
   at  Bc I.at I.Bc
1   1   1    0    0
2  -9  -2    1    1
3  -1 999    1    1
4 999   0    1    0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `data.table`:-

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, I.at := ifelse(at == 999 | at < 0, 1, 0)]
df[, I.Bc := ifelse(Bc == 999 | Bc < 0, 1, 0)]
```

This will give you:-

```
at  Bc I.at I.Bc
1:   1   1    0    0
2:  -9  -2    1    1
3:  -1 999    1    1
4: 999   0    1    0
```

Comment: thanks. however as i mentioned i have 115 variable in my original table and i want to run this for all the variables. This way i have to replicate the process for each variable separately. Is there another way to do it for all the 115 variables once?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Ryan `dplyr` function `mutate_all` is pure magic

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_all(funs(I = ifelse((.)<0|(.)==999,1,0)))
```

---

output

```
   at  Bc at_I Bc_I
1   1   1    0    0
2  -9  -2    1    1
3  -1 999    1    1
4 999   0    1    0
```